# Implementing Enumeratum support for Swagger

Tags: scala, macros, swagger, scala-macros

I'm using Swagger to annotate my API, and in our API we rely a lot on `enumeratum`. If I don't do anything, swagger won't recognize it and just call it `object`.

For example, I have this code that works:

```
sealed trait Mode extends EnumEntry

object Mode extends Enum[Mode] {
  override def values = findValues

  case object Initial extends Mode
  case object Delta extends Mode
}

@ApiModel
case class Foobar(
  @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", allowedValues = "Initial,Delta")
  mode: Mode
)
```

However, I would like to avoid repeating the values as some of my types have many more than this example; I don't want to manually keep that in sync.

The problem is that the `@ApiModel` wants a constant in reference, so I can't do something like `reference = Mode.values.mkString(",")`.

I did try a macro with macro paradise, typically so I can write:

```
@EnumeratumApiModel(Mode)
sealed trait Mode extends EnumEntry

object Mode extends Enum[Mode] {
  override def values = findValues

  case object Initial extends Mode
  case object Delta extends Mode
}
```

...but it doesn't work because the macro pass can't access the `Mode` object.

What solution do I have to avoid repeating the values in the annotation?

Comment: Did you mean `enumeratum`? As in the Scala enum library?

Comment: Yes enumeratum, sorry

Comment: What about using macro to generate a string constant inside `Mode` object and using that constant as a parameter for `@ApiModel` attribute? It is not perfect but should work.

Comment: I tried, that wouldn't work because the `@ApiModel` annotation wants a String constant as a value (and not a reference to a constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This includes code so is too big for a comment.

> I tried, that wouldn't work because the @ApiModel annotation wants a String constant as a value (and not a reference to a constant)

This piece of code compiles just fine for me (notice how you should *avoid* explicitly specifying the type):

```
import io.swagger.annotations._
import enumeratum._

@ApiModel(reference = Mode.reference)
sealed trait Mode extends EnumEntry

object Mode extends Enum[Mode] {
  final val reference = "enum(Initial,Delta)"           // this works!
  //final val reference: String = "enum(Initial,Delta)" // surprisingly this doesn't!

  override def values = findValues

  case object Initial extends Mode
  case object Delta extends Mode
}
```

So it seems to be enough to have another macro that would generate such `reference` string and I assume you already have one (or you can create one basing on the code of [`EnumMacros.findValuesImpl`](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum/blob/ad2471c91329a5ce431c85f8cfb6b7e089b454ba/macros/src/main/scala/enumeratum/EnumMacros.scala#L13-L19)).

**Update**

Here is some code for POC that this can actually work. First you start with following [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html):

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import scala.collection.immutable._


@compileTimeOnly("enable macro to expand macro annotations")
class SwaggerEnumContainer extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro SwaggerEnumMacros.genListString
}

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro to expand macro annotations")
class SwaggerEnumValue(val readOnly: Boolean = false, val required: Boolean = false) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro SwaggerEnumMacros.genParamAnnotation

}


class SwaggerEnumMacros(val c: Context) {

  import c.universe._

  def genListString(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {

    val result = annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      case (xxx@q"object $name extends ..$parents { ..$body }") :: Nil =>
        val enclosingObject = xxx.asInstanceOf[ModuleDef]
        val q"${tq"$pname[..$ptargs]"}(...$pargss)" = parents.head
        val enumTraitIdent = ptargs.head.asInstanceOf[Ident]
        val subclassSymbols: List[TermName] = enclosingObject.impl.body.foldLeft(List.empty[TermName])((list, innerTree) => {
          innerTree match {
            case innerObj: ModuleDefApi =>
              val innerParentIdent = innerObj.impl.parents.head.asInstanceOf[Ident]
              if (enumTraitIdent.name.equals(innerParentIdent.name))
                innerObj.name :: list
              else
                list

            case _ => list
          }
        })

        val reference = subclassSymbols.map(n => n.encodedName.toString).mkString(",")
        q"""
                object $name extends ..$parents {
                  final val allowableValues = $reference
                  ..$body
                }
              """

    }
    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }

  def genParamAnnotation(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    val annotationParams: AnnotationParams = extractAnnotationParameters(c.prefix.tree)
    val baseSwaggerAnnot =
      q""" new ApiModelProperty(
                   dataType = "string",
                   allowableValues = Mode.allowableValues
                   ) """.asInstanceOf[Apply] // why I have to force cast?

    val swaggerAnnot: c.universe.Apply = annotationParams.addArgsTo(baseSwaggerAnnot)

    annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      // field definition
      case List(param: ValDef) => c.Expr[Any](decorateValDef(param, swaggerAnnot))
      // field in a case class = constructor param
      case (param: ValDef) :: (rest@(_ :: _)) => decorateConstructorVal(param, rest, swaggerAnnot)
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "SwaggerEnumValue is expected to be used for value definitions")
    }
  }

  def decorateValDef(valDef: ValDef, swaggerAnnot: Apply): ValDef = {
    val q"$mods val $name: $tpt = $rhs" = valDef
    val newMods: Modifiers = mods.mapAnnotations(al => swaggerAnnot :: al)
    q"$newMods val $name: $tpt = $rhs"
  }


  def decorateConstructorVal(annottee: c.universe.ValDef, expandees: List[Tree], swaggerAnnot: Apply): c.Expr[Any] = {
    val q"$_ val $tgtName: $_ = $_" = annottee
    val outputs = expandees.map {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" => {
        // paramss is a 2d array so map inside map
        val newParams: List[List[ValDef]] = paramss.map(_.map({
          case valDef: ValDef if valDef.name == tgtName => decorateValDef(valDef, swaggerAnnot)
          case otherParam => otherParam
        }))

        q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$newParams) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }"
      }

      case otherTree => otherTree
    }
    c.Expr[Any](Block(outputs, Literal(Constant(()))))
  }


  case class AnnotationParams(readOnly: Boolean, required: Boolean) {
    def customCopy(name: String, value: Any) = {
      name match {
        case "readOnly" => copy(readOnly = value.asInstanceOf[Boolean])
        case "required" => copy(required = value.asInstanceOf[Boolean])
        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Unknown parameter '$name'")
      }
    }

    def addArgsTo(annot: Apply): Apply = {
      val additionalArgs: List[AssignOrNamedArg] = List(
        AssignOrNamedArg(q"readOnly", q"$readOnly"),
        AssignOrNamedArg(q"required", q"$required")
      )

      Apply(annot.fun, annot.args ++ additionalArgs)
    }
  }

  private def extractAnnotationParameters(tree: Tree): AnnotationParams = tree match {
    case ap: Apply =>
      val argNames = Array("readOnly", "required")
      val defaults = AnnotationParams(readOnly = false, required = false)

      ap.args.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(defaults)((acc, argAndIndex) => argAndIndex match {
        case (lit: Literal, index: Int) => acc.customCopy(argNames(index), c.eval(c.Expr[Any](lit)))

        case (namedArg: AssignOrNamedArg, _: Int) =>
          val q"$name = $lit" = namedArg
          acc.customCopy(name.asInstanceOf[Ident].name.toString, c.eval(c.Expr[Any](lit)))

        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Failed to parse annotation params: " + argAndIndex)
      })
  }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
sealed trait Mode extends EnumEntry

@SwaggerEnumContainer
object Mode extends Enum[Mode] {

  override def values = findValues

  case object Initial extends Mode
  case object Delta extends Mode
}


@ApiModel
case class Foobar(@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", allowableValues = Mode.allowableValues) mode: Mode)
```

Or you can do this which I think is a bit cleaner

```
@ApiModel
case class Foobar2(
                    @SwaggerEnumValue mode: Mode,
                    @SwaggerEnumValue(true) mode2: Mode,
                    @SwaggerEnumValue(required = true) mode3: Mode,
                    i: Int, s: String = "abc") {
  @SwaggerEnumValue
  val modeField: Mode = Mode.Delta
}
```

Note that this is still only a POC. Known deficiencies include:

1. `@SwaggerEnumContainer` can't handle case when some fake `allowableValues` is already defined with some fake value (which might be nicer for IDE)
2. `@SwaggerEnumValue` only supports two attributes from the range available in the original `@ApiModelProperty`

Comment: Good, I'll try that!

Comment: @erwan, just in case you are interested - I've added some POC implementation code.

Comment: That did it, thank you! For the record I wasn't correct saying that what I need is `reference = "enum(Initial,Delta)"`, but from your macro (and the magic `final` keyword, that changes everything) I could get it work

Comment: @erwan, I'm not a Swagger user so don't know what you really need. Could you clarify what you really need so I can update the answer for future references as well?

Comment: OK, I edited my question to match what needs to be done. Note that it's not perfect because I need to include the annotation everything I use the enum, but that's just an issue about the Java annotation API and has nothing to do with enumeratum.

Comment: @erwan, I've updated my POC. Take a look - it might be better for you to modify this one rather than the original one. And let me know if you find some bugs.

Comment: thank you - actually I ported your original to the newer macros system in 2.12, and that works: https://gist.github.com/erwan/24a2d8e5c8b0aaca9b646734f371e3c0

I'll try to port your second annotation too, that reduces boilerplate indeed.